# Risk assessment with heavily skewed data

Tags: regression, monte-carlo

I want to do a risk evaluation of (I'm making this up) the price of tea and the temperature. My first approach is to use a multivariate normal random number generator where I tell it the means and covariances of my two variables. I now have simulated data to assess some semblance of probability of outcomes.... or do I.

It turns out the price of tea is highly skewed and my simulated data doesn't share this skewness. I tried using `scipy.stats`'s `skewnorm` but after much experimenting with its parameters could not get simulated data that was both correlated and had the same degree of skewness and kurtosis.

Another approach seems to be to regress the price on the temperature and then use that model as the basis of simulation but I want to ensure that my idea is sound. Here are the proposed steps.

1. Run OLS regression of price on weather
2. Find the mean and std dev of the residuals as error term
3. Convert the reported std error from regression to std dev by multiplying by $\sqrt{N}$
4. Generate independent random variables from normal distribution for each of the regressors (in this case just temp and constant term), error term, and of temp itself.
5. Generate the price by multiplying the rv for temp by the rv for its regressor then adding the rvs for constant error and term.

Does this make sense to do? I can't find any references to doing this sort of thing which leads me to believe it's bad but I can't quite talk myself completely out of it.

Comment: Normal assumptions won't fit data like this. This is a problem best addressed using *extreme value statistical theory*. Coles' book is a good intro https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Statistical_Modeling/SonbBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 One method is *least absolute deviations* regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations  Another is quantile regression as advocated in de Vany's https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hollywood_Economics/5P_KrDloaRkC?hl=en&gbpv=0